# Adding a data field/property to a bookmark in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im starting a new project to morrow where im going to create a new chrome extension. In my extension I will need to set labels on my bookmarks to do this I would like to set the labels on the bookmark object reyrived from the Api is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`chrome.bookmarks`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html) API (and the bookmark feature in Chrome, in general) only offers the option to set a title and URL (and a folder, if desired).

There's no supported way of adding other fields.
If you still want to add some kind of tag (without bookmark folders), just insert them in the title field.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know I will probably use local storage to store the tags linked to each bookmark then but it will make it a bit more cumbersome to do what I want. Still thanks.